# How to target element which have spaces in it's class name css?

Tags: html, css

I have body tag's class like this

```
<body class="cms-page-view cms-home">
```

This body tag have a div with class `col-main` something like

```
<div class="col-main">
</div>
```

I am trying to target this div through css if the body tag have `class = cms-page-view cms-home`

I tried this

```
.cms-page-view cms-home .col-main
{
 width:610px;
}
```

But this does not set width of div to 610px;

How can I target this div only when body tag have `class = cms-page-view cms-home` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use, no need to point both classes.

```
<style>
.cms-page-view .col-main or (.cms-home .col-main)
{
 width:610px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

</style>
<body class="cms-page-view cms-home">

<div class="col-main">Test
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

The same like the ones with a single space

```
<body class="cms-page-view cms-home">
```

the css

```
 .cms-page-view.cms-home
    {
     width:610px;
    }
```

a space simply means multiple classes to the same element.

so in this case body has the class "cms-page-view" and "cms-home"